# Generics Class<? extends Number> explanation

Tags: java, generics

```
public void foo(Class<? extends Number> value) {
    // compilation error
    processNumber(value);
}

public void processNumber(Number num) {
    // do something about this number.
}
```

I would like to call "foo" from any subtype of Number (Integer, Double ..etc) 
Can anyone explain to me how should I do it ?

```
foo(new Integer(5)); // compilation error
```

Comment: You don't need generics here `public void foo(Number value) {}` will work

Comment: one morething java is case sensitive  foo(...) != Foo (...) ;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are passing a `Class` object as a value but `processNumber` takes a `Number`.

You can use this signature:

```
public void foo(Number value)
```

to be able to pass any kind of `Number` into `foo` but keep in mind the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

As a side note: you don't need `foo(new Integer(5));` you can do this instead: `foo(5);`